# Impossible to place lstinputlisting correctly

Tags: graphics, listings

I have this code in a document :

```
\begin{figure}
    \center
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/image.jpg}
    \caption{image}
\end{figure}

The content of file.sh :
\begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Bash,caption={mycaption}]{file.sh}
\end{figure}
Blablabla
```

The source code is placed after the text *Blablabla* and on a single page. This text containt a classic text, a section. It should be placed just after the image. Morever, the source code is cut at end of page and it's missing the half of code... This are the logs :

```
<images/image.jpg, id=122, 442.65375pt x 492.84125pt>
File: images/image.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use images/image.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: images/image.jpg used on input line 292.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 221.32632pt x 246.42001pt.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file
)
Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown lstlisting defaults to 0 on i
nput line 298.
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for T1+cmtt on input line 298.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
(./file.sh)
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 705.87885pt on input line 299.
[9]
```

I am going crazy. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't go crazy, it isn't worth it. Why do you wrap the listing in a `figure` environment? It tells TeX that it is allowed to place it wherever there is enough space. Moreover, figures are not broken across pages.

Comment: For the cut off lines, maybe try `breaklines=true`

Comment: see this for further reference on how to use the `listing`-package: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings
as an alternative, you can also use the `minted`-package

Comment: @gernot, I place it into a wrapper because if I don't do that, the picture is over the text.

Comment: What do you mean by *over the text*? Do you mean that the order in which they appear in the PDF is different from that in your code? If yes, then that is because `figure` is a floating environment, meaning it can move around to get better page breaks. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625 for some suggestions on how to influence that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LaTeX is supposed to keep the strict order image-listing-Blablabla, don't use any `figure` environments. Everything that you wrap into a figure environment will have a certain inclination to move around to where TeX thinks it fits best; moreover, the contents of a `figure` environement does not  break across pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% For the \captionof command, to be used outside of figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{image}
\end{center}

The content of file.sh :
    \lstinputlisting[language=Bash,caption={mycaption}]{file.sh}
Blablabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem ! Do you think if I use this mean to include images I will never again be bothered with this kind of problem ? I started to use LaTeX to focus me on the content of my document but finnally, I am often bothered with this kind of problem.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't know with which problems you are confronted. But I'm sure that all (well most) problems can be solved when using LaTeX correctly.